# Construct star history from GitHub API

Tags: github, github-api

I'm writing a Python program that plot the history of GitHub stars. The StackOverflow allows you to get the number of tags in a certain period of time, the GitHub API does not (as far as I can see). What you *can* do in GitHub is get the list of stargazers at

```
https://api.github.com/repos/{repo}/stargazers
```

If you provide the `{"Accept": "application/vnd.github.v3.star+json"}` header, you get the star time with it (https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/starring/#list-stargazers). From this, it's possible to reconstruct the history. Unfortunately, you can only get at most 40k stargazers, so for large projects this doesn't work well. All lines are straight from 40k upwards:

[image]

Any idea how to use the GitHub API to get the star history from 40k stars on?

Answer (score 0):

You can use GitHub GraphQL API https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/interfaces#starrable

Comment: That's a good suggestion, but unfortunately the GraphQL API doesn't seem to support random pagination access -- one has to flip through _all_ pages (of at most 100 stargazer entries) to get the data.

Comment: Not sure I understand, how else do you want to get all star history, other than flipping through all pages? Looking at the REST doc, there's also a limit of 100 items per page.

Answer (score 0):

You're very close with your [GitHub issue](https://github.com/nschloe/github-trends/issues/20). Instead of using `stargazerCount`, just iterate through all pages (all stargazers for the repo) and save a list of each `starredAt` timestamp. Then to find the total stargazers at a time in the past T, filter that list to timestamps less than T and take the resulting length of the list.

GraphQL Query:

```
{
  repository(owner: "nschloe", name: "github-trends") {
    stargazers (first: 100) {
      pageInfo {
        endCursor
        hasNextPage
      }
      edges {
       starredAt
      }
    }
  }
}
```